# Is better to use .put() or .setValueAt() when working with array maps?

Tags: android, storage

I was thinking if when i have to put something in an arrayMap i should use .put() or .setValueAt() , reading the documentation it seems to be the same thing,so what is the difference and when i sould prefer one or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that `.put()` is used to insert a new item and can be used the first time you place an object in the arrayMap, `.setValueAt()` instead is used to update a value that is already inside the ArrayMap.

`.put()` can be even used to update a value but `.setValueAt()` can't be used to insert a new value the first time.

See the full documentation for all the infos:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap